# Autosys job kick off process

Tags: jobs, autosys

I have an auto sys job named JOB2 which has a dependencies on JOB1.
So the condition mentioned in the job definition for JOB2 will be as below
date_condition:0
condition: s( JOB1)

These two jobs are not in any box, these are two independent jobs.

So my question is when my JOB1 gets into success condition will my JOB2 get kicked off (i.e start automatically)
If so please explain the flow in auto sys?

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the AutoSys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.

Answer (score 0):

A job in Autosys either starts as per schedule ( based on date_condition: and start_time: attributes) or is force started ( manually sendevent to force start)

Considering, JOB1 and JOB2 independent jobs, and JOB2 dependent on JOB1, if JOB2 starts as per schedule, it will stay in AC state until JOB1 is SU, once JOB1 is SU , JOB2 will start automatically. But if you force start JOB2 , it run to completion/failure irrespective of its conditions and status of JOB1.